# Convert an iteration over dictionaries into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have generated 2 dictionaries from 2 input files using conditional statements (not shown). I then aimed to use these 2 dictionaries to identify overlapping values. I would then like to use the output from the iteration as a pandas dataframe directly. To do that, I am first outputting the iteration/for loop  into a file (Output.xls) and then I read the file as pandas dataframe. While this works well, I was wondering if there is a way to use my 'newline' from iteration below directly as an input to an empty pandas dataframe. I couldn't find an option on Python that does that except dataFrame.from_dict . However, this takes in 1 dictionary but I have multiple dictionaries that I am joining together, as well as other variables that I am utilizing.

```
exp1_dict.items() is:
[('lnc3', ['SPATA1', 'AHNAK', 'FGG', 'ERAP1', 'HZ', 'SAASDAS', 'NLRC5', 'HUWE1']), ('lnc2', ['SPATA1', 'FGG', 'TMEM68', 'ATP6AP', 'HUWE1']), ('lnc1', ['SPATA1', 'AHNAK', 'FGG', 'TMEM68', 'ERAP1', 'ATP6AP', 'SAASDAS', 'RAD17', 'HUWE1'])]

exp2_dict.items() is:
[('lnc3', ['SPATA1', 'AHNAK', 'TMEM68', 'ERAP1', 'HZ', 'RAD17', 'NLRC5', 'HUWE1']), ('lnc2', ['SPATA1', 'FGG', 'ERAP1', 'HZ']), ('lnc1', ['SPATA1', 'AHNAK', 'FGG', 'TMEM68', 'ERAP1', 'HZ', 'ATP6AP', 'RAD17']), ('lnc4', ['ERAP1', 'PRSS16', 'HZ', 'NLRC5'])]
```

The code to iterate over dictionaries and generates a 'newline' is:

```
out = open("Output.xls", "w") #generates an empty output file
out.write('Header1\tHeader2\tHeader3\tHeader4\tHeader5\tHeader6\tHeader7\tHeader8\tHeader9\tHeader10\tHeader11\n')#Adds header to output file

intersection_dict={} #empty intersection header
for key, value1 in exp1_dict.items(): #reiterates over the 2 dictionaries
        if key in exp2_dict.keys():
                intersection_dict[key]=list(set(value1).intersection(exp2_dict[key]))
                newline=key, str(f_exp1_dict[key]), str(f_exp2_dict[key]), str('|'.join(value1)), str(len(exp1_dict[key])), str(len(exp1_corr.index)), str('|'.join(exp2_dict[key])), str(len(exp2_dict[key])), str(len(exp2_corr.index)), str('|'.join(intersection_dict[key])), str(len(intersection_dict[key]))
                out.write('\t'.join(newline)+'\n')
```

I then read the Output.xls file using pandas dataframe:

```
out.close()
new_input=pd.read)table("Output.xls", index_col=0)
```

Instead of creating an output file then inputting it as a pandas dataframe, I was wondering if there is a way to write "newline" above to an empty pandas dataframe with the headers above directly.

The Output.xls file looks like this:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5 Header6 Header7 Header8 Header9 Header10    Header11
lnc3    4   4   SPATA1|AHNAK|FGG|ERAP1|HZ|SAASDAS|NLRC5|HUWE1   8   12  SPATA1|AHNAK|TMEM68|ERAP1|HZ|RAD17|NLRC5|HUWE1  8   12  HZ|ERAP1|AHNAK|HUWE1|NLRC5|SPATA1   6
lnc2    2   3   SPATA1|FGG|TMEM68|ATP6AP|HUWE1  5   12  SPATA1|FGG|ERAP1|HZ 4   12  SPATA1|FGG  2
lnc1    1.5 2   SPATA1|AHNAK|FGG|TMEM68|ERAP1|ATP6AP|SAASDAS|RAD17|HUWE1    9   12  SPATA1|AHNAK|FGG|TMEM68|ERAP1|HZ|ATP6AP|RAD17   8   12  ERAP1|RAD17|AHNAK|TMEM68|ATP6AP|SPATA1|FGG  7
```

Comment: Almost certainly, there is an easy way to do this.  However, I'm very unclear as to what the input looks like.  I would have an easier time helping if the problem was simplified.

Comment: @piRSquared thx for comment. I have added the dictionaries above. I hope that helps.

Comment: I assume this is Python 3? Also, what is `f_exp1_dict` and `f_exp2_dict`?

Comment: @Alexander  it is Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) .f_exp1_dict1 and f_exp2_dict2 are other dictionaries that have a value for each corresponding key

Comment: Could you provide the relevant key/value pairs for them so that we can run your code? And `exp1_corr` / `exp2_corr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of lists which you then use to create your dataframe:

```
df = []
for key, value1 in exp1_dict.iteritems(): 
    if key in exp2_dict:
        dict_union = list(set(value1).intersection(exp2_dict[key]))
        col1 = key
        col2 = str(f_exp1_dict[key])
        col2 = str(f_exp2_dict[key])
        col3 = str('|'.join(value1))
        col4 = str(len(exp1_dict[key]))
        col5 = str(len(exp1_corr.index))
        col6 = str('|'.join(exp2_dict[key]))
        col7 = str(len(exp2_dict[key]))
        col8 = str(len(exp2_corr.index))
        col9 = str('|'.join(dict_union))
        col10 = str(dict_union)
        df.append([col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10])

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, to add column names to dataframe i used: df.columns=['Header1', 'Header2'......'Header10']

Answer (score 1):

figuring out all the missing bits like what Alexander brought up with f_exp1_dict is time consuming and frustrating.  But you might find the code below useful.  You'll have to modify to include all the other strings you have.

```
exp1_df = pd.DataFrame([[k, v] for k, v in exp1_dict.items()], columns=['Header1', 'Header4']).set_index('Header1')
exp2_df = pd.DataFrame([[k, v] for k, v in exp2_dict.items()], columns=['Header1', 'Header7']).set_index('Header1')

newlines = pd.concat([exp1_df, exp2_df], axis=1).dropna(subset=['Header4'])
```

exp1_df looks like

```
                                                   Header4
Header1                                                   
lnc3     [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, ERAP1, HZ, SAASDAS, NLRC5...
lnc2                  [SPATA1, FGG, TMEM68, ATP6AP, HUWE1]
lnc1     [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, TMEM68, ERAP1, ATP6AP, SA...
```

exp2_df looks like

```
                                                   Header7
Header1                                                   
lnc3     [SPATA1, AHNAK, TMEM68, ERAP1, HZ, RAD17, NLRC...
lnc2                              [SPATA1, FGG, ERAP1, HZ]
lnc1     [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, TMEM68, ERAP1, HZ, ATP6AP...
lnc4                            [ERAP1, PRSS16, HZ, NLRC5]
```

newlines looks like

```
                                                Header4  \
lnc1  [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, TMEM68, ERAP1, ATP6AP, SA...   
lnc2               [SPATA1, FGG, TMEM68, ATP6AP, HUWE1]   
lnc3  [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, ERAP1, HZ, SAASDAS, NLRC5...   

                                                Header7  
lnc1  [SPATA1, AHNAK, FGG, TMEM68, ERAP1, HZ, ATP6AP...  
lnc2                           [SPATA1, FGG, ERAP1, HZ]  
lnc3  [SPATA1, AHNAK, TMEM68, ERAP1, HZ, RAD17, NLRC...
```